# Jetty priority treatment of health checks?

Tags: jetty, health-monitoring

My Jetty is servicing requests on /myservice/*

My problem is that when the server's queue gets full, the health check requests on /healthcheck start failing.

Is it possible to have a separate queue for my health checks, or is there another way to do this?import java.io.IOException;

Here is an example server:

```
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool;

/**
 * Based on:
 * https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/embedded-examples.html
 */
public class HealthCheckServer
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception
    {
        Server server = new Server(8086);

        QueuedThreadPool qtp = (QueuedThreadPool) server.getThreadPool();
        qtp.setMaxThreads(6);

        ServletHandler handler = new ServletHandler();
        server.setHandler(handler);


        handler.addServletWithMapping(HelloServlet.class, "/hello");
        handler.addServletWithMapping(HealthServlet.class, "/health");

        server.start();

        server.join();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public static class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet
    {
        @Override
        protected void doGet( HttpServletRequest request,
                              HttpServletResponse response ) throws ServletException,
                                                            IOException
        {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10*1000); // 10 sec
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            response.setContentType("text/html");
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
            response.getWriter().println("<h1>Hello from HelloServlet</h1>");
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public static class HealthServlet extends HttpServlet
    {
        @Override
        protected void doGet( HttpServletRequest request,
                              HttpServletResponse response ) throws ServletException,
                                                            IOException
        {
            response.setContentType("text/html");
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
            response.getWriter().println("all good captain");
        }
    }
}
```

If you hit http://localhost:8086/hello 4 times, then http://localhost:8086/health won't be responsive.

Comment: which queue are you referring to?  also, are your health checks requesting static content (served from Jetty's DefaultServlet), or are those healthchecks also dynamically generated?

Comment: QueuedThreadPool server.getThreadPool() <- this queue
ideally dynamically generated but I'm also curious about static if it's easier.

Comment: Oh!  At this point, I suspect you have a bad QueuedThreadPool configuration.  Please describe your ThreadPool setup.  (static or fixed thread pools are almost always worse. far, far, worse.  QueuedThreadPool is far better.)

Comment: Well I'm using Jetty embedded, out of the box I get a QueuedThreadPool, so all default settings I suppose.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt I added a sample server code